# Resource (resx) files always returns english (default) strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019, godot

Im having some trouble using .resx files. Everything was created using windows MAT toolkit extension (the problem occurred regardless of this).

I have two languages (en and es). When I make a new project and use the code below it works:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es");
string temp = MultilingualResources.strings.Hello;
```

The string is returned as "Hallo" so the translation works. But when I do this in GoDot (c#) inside visual code, the string always returns in english no matter which culture or UIculture I specify, but the code is exactly the same. I've tried with resource manager and result is the same. So basically it gets the strings.resx values but not strings.es.resx values. The resx files are embedded resources. Any idea why this is happening and how to make this work?

I also tried using

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: Does [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-localized-exception-messages) help?

Comment: When following this article it returns an exception: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "MultilingualResources.TestApp.strings.es.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "TestApp" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed. But the .resx files are there for sure

Comment: Have you tried using Godot's built-in [localization](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/i18n/internationalizing_games.html) [facilities](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/i18n/localization_using_gettext.html), or is there something preventing you from using them?

Comment: Yes, translations will be used in other projects aswell not only by GoDot. Also the ability for someone who is not technical to use MAT editor for translations..Falling back to default if no translation is found and using multiple languages at once in one app. I see many advantages in resx files, if I could get them to work of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem started for me after the last visual studio (MAC) update (Version 8.6 (build 4520))

Look this:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4664#issuecomment-632986668

This workaround solved my problem.

But, there is a new preview visual studio update in that solve the problem.

Edit: The problem was solved in the new Visual Studio version

Comment: I ended up taking a "backup" of the project (didn't spot any differences between current one and the backup) and it magically started working, I have no Idea why or how it got messed up or started working which bugs me even more (might be the update). Thank you for the link, if I encounter the same issue I will try the suggested workaround.

Comment: I lost 2 days of work thinking the problem was my code. I'm glad I was useful.